# Speed up python loop

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I'm trying to speed up the following python code:

```
for j in range(4,len(var_s),3):
    mag_list.append(float(var_s[j]))
mag_list = [value for value in mag_list if value != 99.]
med_mag = np.median(mag_list)
```

Is there a nice way to combine the two for-loops into one? This way, it is really slow. What I need is to extract every third entry from the var_s list, beginning with the fifths, if the value of that entry is not equal to 99. Of the resulting list, I need the median. 
Thanks!

Comment: `med_mag = np.median([v for v in map(float, var_s[4::3]) if v != 99])`. Not sure if that's faster, but it is shorter.  <shrug>

Comment: What data-type are the various `var_s`?  Do you actually need to construct a float out of each?

Comment: Do you have a sample data set to do some benchmarking on? You've got my curiosity =)

Comment: I agree with @TomasLycken -- I'd do some benchmarking/testing if I had some sample data :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could probably try:

```
mag_list = [value for value in var_s[4::3] if value != 99.]
```

depending on `var_s`, you might do better using `itertools.islice(var_s,4,None,3)`, but that would definitely need to be timed to know.

Perhaps you'd do even better if you stuck with numpy the whole way:

```
vs = np.array(var_s[4::3],dtype=np.float64)  #could slice after array conversion too ...
med_mag = np.median(vs[vs!=99.])
```

Again, this would need to be timed to see how it performed relative to the others.

Comment: You may want to cast it to a float as well? `float(value) for value in var_s[4::3] if value != 99.` Also, there's no need to store the intermediate list if all he needs is the median.

Comment: Using this I get the following error when I try to get the median of mag_list. Any ideas how to fix that?
`med_mag = np.median(mag_list)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2995, in median
    return mean(sorted[indexer], axis=axis, out=out)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2488, in mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 51, in _mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
`

Comment: @frixhax -- I assume that is related to my [comment on your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904282/speed-up-python-loop/15904329?noredirect=1#comment22649677_15904282).  Did you try the only numpy version I posted?

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to use iterators all the way, rather than lists (i.e. switch `[]` to `()` where appropriate)?

Comment: @TomasLycken -- I'm pretty sure that numpy chokes on iterators most of the time.

Answer (score 4):

```
mag_list = filter(lambda x: x != 99, var_s[4::3])
```

Ok so, here are some `timeit` trials, all in Python 2.7.2:

The setup:

```
>>> from random import seed, random
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> from itertools import islice, ifilter, imap
>>> seed(1234); var_s = [random() for _ in range(100)]
```

Using a for loop:

```
>>> def using_for_loop():
...     mag_list = []
...     for j in xrange(4, len(var_s), 3):
...             value = float(var_s[j])
...             if value != 99: mag_list.append(value)
... 
>>> Timer(using_for_loop).timeit()
11.596584796905518
```

Using map and filter:

```
>>> def using_map_filter():
...     map(float, filter(lambda x: x != 99, var_s[4::3]))
... 
>>> Timer(using_map_filter).timeit()
8.643505096435547
```

Using islice, imap, ifilter:

```
>>> def using_itertools():
...     list(imap(float, ifilter(lambda x: x != 99, islice(var_s, 4, None, 3)))) 
... 
>>> Timer(using_itertools).timeit()
11.311019897460938
```

Using a list comprehension and islice:

```
>>> def using_list_comp():
...     [float(v) for v in islice(var_s, 4, None, 3) if v != 99]
... 
>>> Timer(using_list_comp).timeit()
8.52650499343872
>>>
```

In conclusion, using a list comprehension with islice is the fastest, followed by the only slightly slower use of map and filter.

Comment: This is probably slower if anything than a list comprehension, because of the repeated calls up to the lambda function - Python function calls are comparatively expensive. Also, to get the cast to float in there you need to use something like `map(float, filter(...))`, looping twice rather than once, making this even *less* likely to be faster.

Comment: map returns a generator (at least in Python 3), so don't worry about "looping twice".

Answer (score 1):

```
for j in range(4,len(var_s),3):
    value = float(var_s[j])
    if value != 99:
        mag_list.append(value)
med_mag = np.median(mag_list)
```